# android- Application running problem because of emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i am running my application. i am getting this problem "emulator.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. we are sorry for the inconvenience." How to handle this type error at the same time my logcat file showing empty. is any emulator installation problem? How to handle this can anybody help me.

thanks.

Comment: try to kill adb and install again

Comment: what is adb? How to kill adb and how to install it?

Comment: Cancel emulator instance and try to run it again..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Comment: How to cancel emulator instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to command prompt>> and cd path where your android install
cd d:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\
run command
d:>adb kill-server
d:>adb start-server

Comment: after "d:>adb start-server" this command i am getting this * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

Comment: do you have run this tow command in install android directory?

Comment: In console i am getting this                                   [2011-07-04 12:06:13 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2011-07-04 12:06:15 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
[2011-07-04 12:06:17 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 2
[2011-07-04 12:06:19 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 3
[2011-07-04 12:06:21 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 4
[2011-07-04 12:06:23 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 5
[2011-07-04 12:06:25 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 6

Comment: you have kill abd, now start it

Comment: first tell me where you have install android sdk? give me full path.

Comment: thank it's working. But previous it's not working i don't know what's the problem.

Comment: see, to restart adb we have to kill it and start it through command lone.so 
 1) we change path e.g > in my computer i have install android in d drive in like D:\android-sdk-windows 
 
 2) go to plateform-tool folder , and you have found adb.exe right?

Comment: application running successfully. after that once again i am getting the same problem.

Comment: see, to restart adb we have to kill it and start it through command lone.so 
 1) we change path e.g > in my computer i have install android in d drive in like D:\android-sdk-windows 

 2) go to plateform-tool folder , and you have found adb.exe right?
 now copy those path and past it to cmd like : cd D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools 
3) run this command :::    adb kill-server
4) run this command :::    adb start-server

Comment: ya i am done exactly like this. after adb start-server ia m getting  * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully * this in cmd. and in my eclipse console i am getting "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" this message. is any problem is there? or i am done correctly?

Comment: i am getting this error in the logcat.                               07-04 13:02:07.019: ERROR/PackageManager(50): Package com.ibkr.roadbrake requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through these [instructions](http://crossingthechasm.posterous.com/pages/lets-start)

Try Minimum API level=8 (that would be Android 2.2.)

Failing that. Note the Eclipse and JVM versions in the system requirements. I would stick with Eclipse "Classic" (3.5) if you're just trying to get your feet wet. Ensure that your JVM version is compatible.

Comment: How to see the Eclipse and JVM versions in the system requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem with a Xoom emulator.  Not sure what caused it, but removing the AVD and recreating it solved the problem for me.

Comment: i am doing same thing. but till i am getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Window" - > "Show View" - > "Devices" 
After this you will be able to view devices in the bottom of your eclipse.  Choose View Menu option and reset your adb. That's help you.